How to replicate a SoundNote using Play in Wolfram language?
I am trying to precisely replicate SoundNote of different frequencies using the Play function. I am using common notes from Western music theory as a starting point and then will venture off into arbitrary frequencies.
Let's consider the following "C♮4" note as an example:
Sound@SoundNote["C♮4",3,"Piano"]

I know the C Natural note in the fourth octave is of frequency 261.6256 (is there an exact formula for this if you know?). So I try the following:
Play[Sin[2 Pi 261.6256 t],{t,0,3}]

But it doesn't sound the same. Is there a built-in way to get the exact wave function used by the SoundNote function?

I don't know about getting a formula, but you can get a list of the sound data by using AudioData. You could then do Fourier analysis on the data maybe? Or look at the Spectrogram of the sound

What exactly is your purpose? Instruments do not produce pure (sine) tones, they have a specific timbre. If you want to look at the frequency decomposition of the sound of an instrument, use sound-analysis functionalities (like Spectrogram), if you want to produce a sound, use SoundNote, which uses MIDI emulator to generate a real-like sound of an instrument.

And regarding the formula, look up equal temperament or scientific pitch notation.

Final Update
Here is the whole code, and an explanation of each part afterwards. It takes a while to run (about 1 min on my laptop) because the Play part is very slow when it calculates the audio for the resulting function.
You can listen to the comparison here (original note first, reconstruction 2nd)
nearestOverUnderTone := If[# < f0, 1/Round[f0/#]  f0, Round[#, f0]] &

note = Sound@SoundNote["C\[Natural]4", 3, "Piano"];
f0 = 440*2^(-9/12);
(*resample to a highly-divisible multiple of f0*)
SR = Round[120    f0];
note = AudioResample[note, SR];

adat = AudioData@note;
noteLength = AudioLength@note // QuantityMagnitude;
partitionSize = Round[noteLength/20];
fourierCutOff = Floor[partitionSize/2];

partedDat = Partition[#, partitionSize] & /@ adat;

freqTicks = Subdivide[0, SR/2, fourierCutOff - 1];

fourierList = 
  Map[TimeSeries[
     Thread[{freqTicks, Take[Abs@Fourier@#, fourierCutOff]}]] &, 
   partedDat, {2}];
pks = Map[FindPeaks[#, 5, 0, 0.1] &, fourierList, {2}];
allPosPeaks = Union@Flatten@Map[#["Times"] &, pks, {2}];
groupedDat = GatherBy[allPosPeaks, nearestOverUnderTone];
sines = Sin[2  Pi   nearestOverUnderTone[#]   t] & /@ 
   groupedDat[[All, 1]];

getTimes[ts_] := Total[ts[#]] & /@ groupedDat

timeGrouped = Map[getTimes, fourierList, {2}];
timeGrouped = Transpose[timeGrouped, 2 <-> 3];
timeDuration = partitionSize/SR;
tSpec = Range[1, 2  (fourierList // Dimensions // Last), 
    2]  timeDuration/2;

timeIndexedGrouped = Map[Thread[{tSpec, #}] &, timeGrouped, {2}];


wInts = Map[Interpolation /@ # &, timeIndexedGrouped, {1}];
wIntsExplicitT = Map[#[t] &, wInts, {2}];
intChannels = wIntsExplicitT . sines;

play = Play[{intChannels[[1]], intChannels[[2]]}, {t, tSpec[[1]], 
    tSpec[[-1]]}, SampleRate -> SR]

pDat = AudioData@play;
lAud = ListPlay[pDat, SampleRate -> SR];
(*cutoff at 12th overtone*)
lF = LowpassFilter[lAud, Quantity[12 f0, "Hz"]];
joined = AudioJoin[note, lF]

I explicitly use Fourier here on the time-partitioned audio data. The methodology is pretty similar to the previous update however.
I define my helper function that rounds to the nearest over/undertone and resample to a nice multiple of the fundamental frequency:
nearestOverUnderTone := If[# < f0, 1/Round[f0/#] f0, Round[#, f0]] &

note = Sound@SoundNote["C\[Natural]4", 3, "Piano"];
f0 = 440*2^(-9/12);
(*resample to a highly-divisible multiple of f0*)
SR = Round[120   f0];
note = AudioResample[note, SR];

I then grab the audio data, and partition into 20 equal-length samples. I then take the first half of the DFT of each partition and take the Abs magnitude. I store this as TimeSeries data that looks like {freq, Abs of DFT at freq}:
adat = AudioData@note;
noteLength = AudioLength@note // QuantityMagnitude;
partitionSize = Round[ noteLength/20];
fourierCutOff = Floor[partitionSize/2];

partedDat = Partition[#, partitionSize] & /@ adat;

freqTicks = Subdivide[0, SR/2, fourierCutOff - 1];

fourierList = Map[
   TimeSeries[
     Thread[{freqTicks, Take[Abs@Fourier@#, fourierCutOff]}]] &,
   
   partedDat, {2}];



I then find the peaks in the absolute DFT with an aggressive blurring scale of 5, and a minimum peak size of 0.1. I record all the unique positions that these peaks occur at, and gather them by their nearest over/undertone:
pks = Map[FindPeaks[#, 5, 0, 0.1] &, fourierList, {2}];
allPosPeaks = Union@Flatten@ Map[#["Times"] &, pks, {2}];
groupedDat = GatherBy[allPosPeaks, nearestOverUnderTone];

I then create my over/undertone sine waves, and get the total abs DFT at each peak group:
sines = Sin[2 Pi  nearestOverUnderTone[#]  t] & /@ 
   groupedDat[[All, 1]];

getTimes[ts_] := Total[ts[#]] & /@ groupedDat

timeGrouped = Map[getTimes, fourierList, {2}];
timeGrouped = Transpose[timeGrouped, 2 <-> 3];

To make the sound smooth, we interpolate the peak groups as a function of time:
timeDuration = partitionSize/SR;
tSpec = Range[1, 2 (fourierList // Dimensions // Last), 
    2] timeDuration/2;

timeIndexedGrouped = Map[Thread[{tSpec, #}] &, timeGrouped, {2}];


wInts = Map[Interpolation /@ # &, timeIndexedGrouped, {1}];
wIntsExplicitT = Map[#[t] &, wInts, {2}];


And finally dot with our sine waves to get our two channel functions:
intChannels = wIntsExplicitT . sines;
play = Play[{intChannels[[1]], intChannels[[2]]}, {t, tSpec[[1]], 
  tSpec[[-1]]}, SampleRate -> SR]

The peaks start to deviate from the overtone frequencies around $12 f_0$, so I apply a LowpassFilter to the new sound, and compare it to the original note:
pDat = AudioData@play;
lAud = ListPlay[pDat, SampleRate -> SR];
(*cutoff at 12th overtone*)
lF = LowpassFilter[lAud, Quantity[12 f0, "Hz"]];
joined = AudioJoin[note, lF]

This is really sounding good now, but It doesn't appear to generalizes well to other frequencies:
nF = sines[[All, 1]]/(2 Pi  f0  t);
newSines = Sin[2 Pi*nF*440*t];
newChannels = wIntsExplicitT . newSines;
Play[{newChannels[[1]], newChannels[[2]]}, {t, tSpec[[1]], 
  tSpec[[-1]]}, SampleRate -> SR]

So you probably have to repeat this whole over/undertone analysis for each note you want to model.
Update
After a little more thought, I realized that the note should mostly consist of overtones.
I first get the note. I resample to Round[30 f0] as I was having issues with high-frequency noise when fitting:
note = Sound@SoundNote["C\[Natural]4", 3, "Piano"];
f0 = 261.6256;
SR = Round[30  f0];
note = AudioResample[note, SR];

I then calculate the Spectrogram, and extract the spectrogram array. I calculate the intensity at each (frequency,time) binning and rescale:
spec = Spectrogram[note, 2^12, SampleRate -> SR];
arr = Level[spec, {-1}][[1]] // Normal;
intensityMap = Map[Norm[#] &, arr, {2}];
intensityMap = 1 - Rescale[intensityMap];

Image[intensityMap] // ImageResize[#, {400, 200}] & // 
 Magnify[#, 2] &



We can see evenly spaced lines, so hopefully these line up with the overtone series.
The frequency domain runs from 0 to SR/2, so we can interpret our frequency bins as such:
freqTicks = intensityMap // Dimensions // First;
maxFreq = SR/2;
freqRange = Range[0, maxFreq, maxFreq/(freqTicks - 1)];

Let's look at the frequency intensity spectrum in one time bin far from the attack of the note, and see if it lines up with our overtone series (I.e. multiples of f0):
freqIntensity = Thread[{freqRange/f0, intensityMap[[All, 10]]}];
fPlot = ListLinePlot[freqIntensity, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, maxFreq/f0}, All}, 
  GridLines -> {Range[0, 30], All}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(f\), \(f0\)]\)", 
    "rel. intensity"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium]]


And indeed the peaks do line up! There does appear to be some deviation after $\frac{f}{f_0} \gtrapprox 10$ though.
Let's now grab these peaks, and show them as points on the plot as well. I found FindPeaks with a blurring parameter of 2 works here
p = FindPeaks[intensityMap[[All, 10]], 2];
peaks = Thread[{freqRange[[p[[All, 1]]]]/f0, p[[All, 2]]}];
pPlot = ListPlot[peaks, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[fPlot, pPlot, PlotRange -> {{0, maxFreq/f0}, All}]


We can now extend this to all the time stamps to get the over/undertones as a function of time in the note.
I first define a helpful functions that converts a frequency index to an over/undertone:
nearestOverUnderTone[k_Integer] := With[{fRel = freqRange[[k]]/f0},
  If[fRel < 1, f0/Round[1/fRel], f0  Round[fRel]]
  ]

And now convert the indices to nearest over/undertone index and frequency, create our basis functions and extract our weights. I had issues with high-frequency ringing, so I only take overtones up to $10 f_0$. You can also see in the intensity plot the peaks start to deviate away from $n f0$ around $n = 10$:
peakIndices = p[[All, 1]];
presentHarmonics = nearestOverUnderTone /@ peakIndices;
cutOff = 10  f0;
presentHarmonics = Select[presentHarmonics, # <= cutOff &];
peakIndices = Take[peakIndices, Length@presentHarmonics];


basisList = Sin[2   Pi*presentHarmonics*t];
weights = intensityMap[[peakIndices, All]];

If we immediately dot our basis with our weights, the sound will sound "choppy" because of the time discretization, so we should smoothly interpolate our weights:
nTimeSteps = weights // Dimensions // Last;
timeStamps = Subdivide[0, 3, nTimeSteps - 1];
timeStampedWeights = Map[Thread[{timeStamps, #}] &, weights, {1}];
ints = Interpolation /@ timeStampedWeights;


And now we are finally ready to create our sound as a function of time expressed as a linear sum of overtones:
continuousFun[t_] = basisList . (#[t] & /@ ints);
play = Play[continuousFun[t], {t, 0, 3}, SampleRate -> SR];

And listening to them one after another, we see we are starting to really sound like a piano, though it's not perfect
AudioJoin[note, play]

If we hope that the relative overtone intensities is constant with notes, then we can create a functional piano for any frequency (this is still far from perfect, but it is a start):
createFunctionalPiano[f_] := 
 Module[{cutOff, SR, basisFuns, 
   ints = Uncompress@
     "1:eJztl2lQk9cexl9BEeEqEcWKDIi1AsoWNgVEnqjIhVYpFyhaaktYwiKBcNmUAj\
W2iLQgprYayiJJAasMYqgRUbYUDIGUAoEQUUSxapWikLrVunGzMG3xztwvd/\
iW58PzvP9zznty5ry/\
zJyzIpwREKVPEETybIVtjU1OiZqjrIwU5puQQktKZNDDUmITor1TEyJSYhkJUbOmDdb6e5\
VETGnqQZcSNf/v/bHKqWPnKk3ZPX0qX+\
VUDq6vNSorZ9Xo1yx5nsI2pqYw4hXLi4gipq1qWpWs/\
FXvMHoybfrcNGVlSPwl9lGl2qFOGX6TKzUyVf8CD5XuTbXLcbFNqYdT/U8Qq9IfU+\
NewEClyanxBCVEJS2K+j1tiq1Kcyjq93Uof26a9rTlGysevGhpNDojkZZE9Q+\
LiKNFbkxKCkv3ZiTFRy36r+0iq9xB5Y4qd1Jvo8pdVL5W5etU7qpyN/X+\
k9XhoA5HdTipw1kdLupYq451U9/tz930nCCTvu8YQhct2EDe14+\
Q5Ai5v44Ui60bnj7e1QuPZbTlTgNieDyrsia/\
24HM1YMnN5A6seeYl4ljXgciP2t5SIsR4u7z2syEgEaQqzIvmVnWgUnYFix4UQOKc+\
L44j2nIZfXJC/MPwXeSvubjUYnwGw5Q/TkcWHe5nl6hHYUzIljm1zKUzH9o7+GjYZ1Dev/\
B+tqyWF4qOUfK3pGIYuhBBuk/4Jnd81pGf+8iWd69LD7K2/Ak9zTElozjCvr+\
uibpZcRNM87LHb7JbQfvPDeRz4ymO3PGj9sfQlewdoDdyZl4MSxzS+\
QZVj2vEfEuyBFfQzBvGqq+C+JqxIvx0lAjG4uu9bbBRsd+o6iN4RgsdC+ypCrYV3D+\
oyxbiPZzl/vdg2vBK+SDxUMgjictu32CRmudLhHRyZIkWQWn1O6rw8B91ax4x/\
3gh5XYSXy7IF0XXBQUmY3dMe2mCx+Loa/K2H4h1gEPt/PZW9/O1yD+\
VzfhjYQRleNu5YIkEu+VmVb1gDmGb+h4/\
oCJO5kH94lbUemtHGSVCsGVTrZRenlaVjXsD5jrOu6zdV6f80lVN2SDta8KUUBadUR9mYJ\
qMVa6dvdu8C7ee2jBfWdmJ2zL8K6tBNWc/TX+\
sd2ILGs3MC8QQiKtbmMY9WEXCt2dB9Rh0KPdi6f0YCOkNtv+i07D07ZkUZ9Oh+\
9D7G2VasW8smFPx6orgTV7CqX+L0EI2Tax5t+\
LAOzWmDybki6hnUN6zPGul37agu9JhkufvOvhR/4yvCqP7Xk+\
tsDyDGoTb7I7kdHcYHcRq8P2WM/N5WzJfCJZy4QGEvA5HgmRr/\
sBr9v1qJDEWKQeZcj08sV7A+nx+TlihDDv719wU0ReF/\
sKqovUuRpN27RFSFsJGd6NwW0wee0ac1sUSsEZrfm73jwAwTvkPyeOHA0rGtYnzHWmUuvj\
36rfwnUIoneBScp/FGdYX+kDzZnY4w/\
oUqwM6KX5T7cjYvycS7JqRODeq0HOZvbwVvgNbZ1nxjZbm8Mr7MXg1Jd17DxPcUddRPP2i\
tOhHy/gfC8chHo/aYTps5C5EcHUzvWt4LMtbvT8E4TnhaeX/zvpBZ0Lf9yd/EWAZg/\
FxhvqC7RsK5hfcZYP35n+f5hT8XdcUlGbYqkB/\
XhjNRn8zuw42CXfpCtEMy2jFDpSDOWBh00DLXgo16XZMAkzqKwfJvfLIdGsFJajcL2XgC5\
7ksGq58PyvcD7S/SjsNcp2yyvLASzAO/nbgVyAXl8VsVXwyUgmeFzkcsLgRB5K/OBytSx+\
76qiUsEMwPGLbPgzSsa1ifMdYd7TZU55sOQ8dpdCO5ZAB667ukQ08lsOgtXeqSrzirlBnv\
rRuVoNGVKCdV9uHYvh7DDfsk2PpA+\
6uqVMUZ5pXld7JnQvCvfh7404lWSEcYqSsn20DZYmViJRcgRjpcUf9pEwrnGXpESs5BYMp\
6eezbUzihN1TeqNuAGKPqUC+7ZhDXrQd1xoo0rGtYnzHWtSI+L8zWGUROv/UBao/ifH6+\
fuX4zh7EsOuiHhwTQ/DxAU4YpxuZ7hEhqW/9BFLo78Kh8Q745P5qw6/\
4Aa4vVvJGljRgMDzNaqt2A8ir6feGa5rhmr3GZ9C8CbqFE+\
wNzefAW7Z3d1Z8FZgfWoTvEleAVK89YSmqAfFE9+TX23hg2g+\
1H9LL1bCuYX3GWF9qHHjjSY8MKUGBazxDJcgfe+\
DyyVkROJPdJu6WreCM6WQz2OcgtznaTI+vBWuNTnH3+tPwH84b8kjjwL/\
uflzW5QowUzs9LW5wQHXweVkYeRQU38zWwxZfg1jU/X5IyFFw7j4K/\
Cxa0X6vcu6HkgIItpjsygnPBxO8vMDiDBAeWRk1+\
701rGtYnzHWA1jFcaMrerGjfLZlkqMY1YVtpY9cxNgp2//0VzshOM0D9+/\
71sGf6UnNLaxS3ClzrLZsroOrh1vTyW11IJ/SrteX8kDxkfbu/\
vQ4yEJZadzGUyD2NOeIgqpAElYm7HT/\
DqytMsvqV1wQD81KrDzKQIRTd2cdKgERVfqCr3sExBx7y3rnmP/J+n8AoSEarw=="},
  SR = 7849;
  cutOff = 2 Pi *2616.;
  basisFuns = 
   Sin[2 Pi*{0.25`, 1.`, 2.`, 3.`, 4.`, 5.`, 6.`, 7.`, 8.`, 9.`, 
      10.`}*f*t];
  basisFuns = Select[basisFuns, #[[1, 1]] <= cutOff &];
  ints = Take[ints, Length@basisFuns];
  func[t_] := basisFuns . (#[t] & /@ ints);
  
  Play[func[t], {t, 0, 3}, SampleRate -> SR]
  ]

Original Post
One thing we can do is get an approximation of the note as a Cosine series by using FourierDCT
We first get the data of the sound using AudioData:
note = Sound@SoundNote["C\[Natural]4", 3, "Piano"];
dat = AudioData[note];

This comes out in 2 separate channels. I am just going to focus on one channel for now but you could do this for both:
dat = First@dat;

Now we take the FourierDCT of type III of dat, and normalize by length:
l = Length@dat;
cc = FourierDCT[dat, 3]/Sqrt[l];

And let's just take the 100 largest coefficients of the DCT:
trunc = PositionLargest[Abs@cc, 100] // Flatten;
coeffs = cc[[trunc]];

And dot with our DCT basis functions to get our functional representation:
basis = Cos[Pi (# - 1/2) t] & /@ trunc;
ClearAll[approx]
approx[t_] = coeffs . basis;
approx[t] // Short


And now we can compare how the two sound:
xg = N[Range[0, l - 1]]/l;
new = Map[approx, xg];

approxAudio = Audio[new];
AudioPlay[approxAudio]
Pause[3]
AudioPlay[note]

This is definitely still imperfect; there's still a lot of ringing and the approximation really misses the "attack" part of the note when the piano key is first depressed, but it is better than pure sine wave approximation.

The "formula" part of the question is straightforward. Say an A note is 440 Hz, then the C above that is 3 steps, each of size 2^(1/12). Hence the frequency of the C is:
440*2^(3/12)//N
523.251

This is an octave above the C you were looking for, so divide this by 2 to get the exact value:
N[(440/2)*2^(3/12), 20]

which gives the answer to 20 decimal places.
